# Show get_sub_field value if it exists

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields in a WP build. I have the following:

`<h1 class="title"><?php echo get_sub_field('title'); ?></h1>`

How do I only show this if someone's filled in the title field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the whole line conditional, like this:

```
$sub_field_title = get_sub_field('title');
if (!empty($sub_field_title)) {
   echo '<h1 class="title">' . $sub_field_title . '</h1>';
   }
```